# How to call Cpp function from C file

Tags: c++, c, codeblocks

I have two different projects in a single workspace and both projects are cpp projects. When I am calling cpp function from one project to another project but it is not working and showing **undefined reference** to Function Name. at the time of linking.

Calling file is in .c with project name ABC and definition file is .cpp with project name CDE

Please help

Comment: Does your title have anything to do with your question? If so, would you mind clarifying where C comes into play?

Comment: Thanks gha.st for quick reply , I have Update my question with more description , Please have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague but the problem could be name mangling. Put your C++ function in an `extern "C" { ... }` block in order to give it C linkage and prevent the compiler from mangling the name.

Comment: I have already tried this but still facing the same issue(Undefined Reference). will you please elaborate it more so that I can try again.

Comment: So, perhaps the problem is in path where cpp -files located or incorrect run of compiler?